# How to map a range form data to X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a dataset that the age field is represent as range, such as 0--8,9--17,18--23,etc.

```
year,gender,age,population
2002,Female,0--8,0
2002,Female,9--17,25
2002,Female,18--20,291
2002,Female,21--23,375
2002,Female,24--26,212
2002,Female,27--29,108
2002,Female,30--38,74
2002,Female,39--47,0
```

I want to use this age in the X axis of my barplot. How can I calculate the domain in this range form? Seems like I can't just use

```
d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return +d.age})
```

Below is my code until creating yScale:

```
    function dataProcessor(d) {
    return {
        year: +d.year,
        gender: d.gender,
        age: +d.age,
        population: +d.population

    };
}



width = 600
height = 400



var svg = d3.select("svg");

var margin = {top: 50,
           right: 50,
           bottom: 50,
           left: 100
        };

chartWidth = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
chartHeight = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

g = svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv('years.csv', dataProcessor).then(function(data) {



});

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
          .padding(0.1)
          .domain([0, data.length-1])

var populationMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
       return +d.population
});

var populationMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return +d.population
});

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([populationMin, populationMax])
               .range([height, 0]);
```

Comment: Why not map by index and then replace the tick text with the `d.age`?

Comment: @Coola what is map by index? How can I do it? I'm new to d3

Comment: For example map the range to `[0,dataset.length]`. For more detailed explanation please provide more code for review.

Comment: @Coola This is what I plan to do: var xScale = d3.scaleLiner()
            .domain([0, d.ageMax])
            .range([0, chartWidth]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);  I think you mean replace the d.ageMax to d.length? How can I specify the length here?

Comment: Add your full code for the bar chart to the question for review and I can easily help you solve the issue or you can set the domain to `domain([0,d.length-1])` and then when you call the axis for the tick labels call the age values from your dataset.

Comment: @Coola I add my code until yScale, for the "data.length-1"  there is an error said "data" not defined.

Answer (score 0):

These age ranges aren’t continuous; they’re ordinal. Essentially, these are labels that happen to have a particular order, not numbers.

Rather than use `d3.scaleLinear()`, use [`d3.scaleBand()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/v2.2.2/README.md#scaleBand) where the domain is `["0--8", "9--17", ... , "39--47"]`. `d3.scaleBand()` maps from a discrete domain to continuous range. It’s designed to be used for things like bar charts, so it also includes a `bandwidth()` method to tell you how wide each band is based on the size of your domain, range, and any padding that you’ve configured the scale for.

```
let x = d3.scaleBand(["0--8", "9--17", "18--20", "21--23",
                      "24--26", "27--29", "30--38" , "39--47"]);
    .range([[0, width]);
```

Then (assuming you already have a data-bound selection called `bars`) you can position each bar with something like

```
bars.
    .attr("x", d => x(d.age))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

Comment: I did used ScaleBand(), I upload my code to the question. Can you help me check my Scaleband() part. How about the domain for the xScale?